# How can I attach new levels with specific values for specific rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column for the name of individuals and columns for results.
Now I want to attach a new column with either 1 , 2 or NA depending on the individual.

I have a vector with all the individuals which are level 1 and one for individuals from level 2

How can I attach a collumn to this data frame that goes something like this:
 *if* dataframe$individual is (1,3,6,7) value in column is 1, *if* dataframe$individual is (2,5,8) value in column is 2, *else* value is NA

I hope I made it clear with the example what i am looking for.
Thanks for the help

Comment: You can use `ifelse`. Also, please show some example data

Comment: ..and check out `%in%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
dat$newCol <- with(dat, ifelse(individual %in% c(1,3,6,7), 1,
                      ifelse(individual %in% c(2,5,8), 2, NA)))
```